# reference a php string in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, string

I am using the following code to generate a random string in php, and then am storing this in my database like so:

```
<?php $allowance_promo = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 8); ?>
```

I am then using my query to store this value into the database:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE internal_users SET allowance_promo = '$allowance_promo' WHERE user_id ='{$_SESSION['id']}'");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I then use another query to retrieve the value:

```
$query2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM internal_users WHERE user_id ='{$_SESSION['id']}'");
$result2 = mysql_query($query2); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

$check = $row['allowance_promo'];
```

Then i am trying to use jquery to check if the value entered into my input field matches the one in the database like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.promo_check').click(function() {
var discountCode = "<?php echo $check; ?>";
var codeEntered = $("input[name='promo']").val();

 if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
    $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
 }
  });
});
</script>
```

However i am having some difficulty getting it to work using a php string. If i use normal text like var discountCode = '123'; then it works, but when i try and use `var discountCode = "<?php echo $check; ?>"`; it wont work. Can someone please show me what i am doing wrong. Thanks,

Comment: can't find  $check; in you code ??

Comment: you use javascript code in side loop ?

Comment: alos why you use another query to get random generated code ???

Comment: <script>
var discountCode = "<?php echo $allowance_promo; ?>";
  $('.promo_check').click(function() {
var codeEntered = $("input[name='promo']").val();
 if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
    $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
 }
  });
</script>

Comment: use above code and check

Comment: ok i have post my answer :)

Comment: Seem to be a bit insecure if you store `discountCode` in JS. User can just display source of your page and see what `discoutCode` is correct one.

Comment: "it wont work" is not a meaningful diagnosis. What does the generated Javascript look like? What is the corresponding value stored in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your script by the script below. Put `discountCode` outside the click event handler and remove `$(document).ready();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var discountCode = "<?php echo $allowance_promo; ?>";
    $('.promo_check').click(function() {
        var codeEntered = $("input[name='promo']").val();
        if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
            $('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

</script>
```